# Nginx take URL out of Request URI

Tags: nginx

Inside my server block I have something like this

location /abc/ {
                rewrite ^/abc/(.*)$ $1 redirect;
}

The use case:
If a user sends in a request like this "http://mywebsite.tld/abc/http://website.com/afunny.jpg" the user should be redirected to "http://website.com/afunny.jpg".

This is not working in Firefox, as intended.
It redirects to http://mywebsite.tld/website.com/afunny.jpg.
Skipping the http:// creates an endless redirect loop.

Is there a way to fix this or is it impossible?

Comment: It's a bad idea. Why not to use query arguments? `http://example.com/redir?go=http://example.net/page/`?

Comment: The problem is I cannot control the behaviour of the incoming requests. It is a legacy application that corrupts links and sends
http://somewebsite.tld/http://theactualurl.tld/image.jpg